# Loading Database Records into a table using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-table

I have been given a code to modify for database records on a website using ajax.

I have the function correctly querying data but the table displayed does not get any of the records displayed with in it. I have code of the functions and the html below.

Please see this link of current version: http://www.eng.nene.ac.uk/~10406206/CSY2028/Ajax/Ajax.html

**Function of loadrecords with a callback not sure why a callback is used**

```
<script language="Javascript">

var xmlHttpReq = false;
var xmlHttpReq2 = false;
var xmlHttpReq3 = false;

function loadDatabaseRecordsCallback () 
{
    if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) 
{            
   alert ("From Server (Load Records):List.php" + xmlHttpReq.responseText);

    var record = xmlHttpReq.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('record');
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i ++)
    {
    var rec = record[i];

    var id = rec.getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].firstChild.data;
    var carname = rec.getElementsByTagName("CARNAME")[0].firstChild.data;
    var fueltype = rec.getElementsByTagName("FUELTYPE")[0].firstChild.data;
    var transmission = rec.getElementsByTagName("TRANSMISSION")[0].firstChild.data;
    var enginesize = rec.getElementsByTagName("ENGINESIZE")[0].firstChild.data;
    var doors = rec.getElementsByTagName("DOORS")[0].firstChild.data;
    var total = rec.getElementsByTagName("TOTAL")[0].firstChild.data;
    var available = rec.getElementsByTagName("AVAILABLE")[0].firstChild.data;
    appendRecord (id, carname, fueltype, transmission, enginesize, doors, total, available);
    }
}
}

function loadDatabaseRecords () 
{
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    alert ("To Server (Load Records): List.php");

    xmlHttpReq.open('GET', "List.php", true);
xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = loadDatabaseRecordsCallback; 
xmlHttpReq.send(null);
}
```

**on the same page as the function is the table which is below**

```
<body>
  <form name="f1">
    <input value="Load Database" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:loadDatabaseRecords()'></p>
  </form>
  <table id="DBTable"  border="2">
    <tr>
      <td width="20">ID</td>
      <td width="100">Car Name</td>
      <td width="100">Fuel Type</td>
      <td width="100">Transmission</td>
      <td width="80">Engine size</td>
      <td width="20">Doors</td>
      <td width="20">Total</td>
      <td width="20">Available</td>
     </tr>
     <form name="myform">
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="carname"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fueltype"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="transmission"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="enginesize"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="doors"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="available"></td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="add" onClick="JavaScript:addNewRecord()"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="update" onClick="JavaScript:updateRecord()"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="delete" onClick="JavaScript:deleteRecord()"></td>
     </tr>
     </form>
  </table>
</body>
```

**The function calls the List.php which is coded as follows**

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect ("194.81.104.22", "********", "*****");
  mysql_select_db ("*******");

  $query = "SELECT * from XYZ";
  $result = mysql_query ($query);


 for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows ($result); $i ++)
  {        
    $row = mysql_fetch_object ($result);
    print "<b>Car Name:</b> <i>$row->CARNAME</i><br>";
    print "<b>Fuel Type:</b> <i>$row->FUELTYPE</i><br>";
    print "<b>Transmission:</b> <i>$row->TRANSMISSION</i><br>";
    print "<b>Total:</b> <i>$row->TOTAL</i><br>";
    print "<b>Available:</b> <i>$row->AVAILABLE</i><br><br>";
  }

  mysql_close ($link);
?>
```

So, if you have seen the website you will see that you press the load database button and a box appears with all the database entries. However, once you press enter the table on the page remains empty.

My question is why?
can you explain to me where the problem is?

New to Ajax and apologies if I broke rules on posts it's my first one.

Comment: I don't know about AJAX rules, but this seems like a terrible idea to me.  You're exposing your database directly to a PHP page?  No validation?  No authentication or authorization?  No worries about SQL injection?  No sensitive data in that database?  If it's an academic assignment, I'd say this is an example of what not to do.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. This is a code been given to us. Pretty basic stuff but I have no idea how to edit something that is so badly written.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with php, but I remember from my asp + ajax experiences:

You bring data back to your browser, but you should "re-paint" the page - you can do this in javascript, or may-be PHP has some ready solutions for this.

When you validated your method appendRecord receive valid values - find your table (DBTable) with javascript by id, and update the values of the row  / columns by your record.

I'd recommend you to take a look on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: the only thing I achieved was listing the data but all it does is delete the table on the page. lost...

Comment: try to play with single value - put it on the page, return it with ajax, try to update its value. probably you will need to update the value by JavaScript (client side). This will give your the direction.

Comment: All I am trying to achieve is getting the values from my database to load into the table on the website using the load button. I am a novice programmer trying to learn from this example. Clearly the code given is useless.

Comment: what do your appendRecord method does? if you add alert inside - do you see right values?

Comment: think there was a appendRecord function which is now unused? add alert where exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the link i did come across that earlier. unfortunately the table I have already needs to be used as a way of updating records.

Comment: it is too long for me to send on here. It will not allow me to answer my own question. how can i send you this code?

Comment: ok, add inside this method alert, and display one of received values - are they ok? if yes - post only row you update the grid with this values.

Comment: Nothing changes. When the load database button is pressed the database details are just displayed with in the open dialog box instead of being written into the table on the page

Answer (score 0):

You bring data back to your browser, but you should "re-paint" the page - you can do this in javascript, or may-be PHP has some ready solutions for this.

When you validated your method appendRecord receive valid values - find your table (DBTable) with javascript by id, and update the values of the row / columns by your record.

Comment: When you validated your method appendRecord receive valid values - find your table (DBTable) with javascript by id, and update the values of the row / columns by your record.